# How to wait for all instances of a specific selector to load in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

As the title says is there any way I can wait for all instances of a specific class, say a selector called "div.ticket" to load. I tried using `waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "networkidle2"});` but it takes too long, I am trying to get a pdf out of the page with multiple tickets in it all inside a div having class "ticket" but the ticket isn't obtained properly(images and some text missing) when I run it without any waitFor. I also tried `page.waitFor('.ticket');` but it didn't give the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wait for **all** elements you must know how much of them should be. Here is an example when each `.ticket` is created every 1 second. So when you know that should be 3 tickets on the page you should wait for `page.waitFor('.ticket:nth-of-type(3)')`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const html = `
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="tickets"></div>
        <script>
            const ticketsContainer = document.querySelector('.tickets');
            let i = 0;
            const timeInterval = setInterval(
                () => {
                    const newTicket = document.createElement("div");
                    newTicket.innerHTML = "ticket" + i;
                    newTicket.className = "ticket";
                    ticketsContainer.appendChild(newTicket);
                    i++;
                    if (i >= 3) {
                        clearInterval(timeInterval);
                    }
                }, 
                1000
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);
    // await page.waitFor('.ticket');
    await page.waitFor('.ticket:nth-of-type(3)');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'image.png' });
    await browser.close();
})();
```